# jQuery isn't working in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile, wordpress-theming

Link

I'm developing this wordpress child theme. Everything works perfectly on all desktop sizes, but when I run the site on my iphone, all the .remove(), .appendTo(), .insertAfter() etc. won't work.

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery*/
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

//Add header search form
var search = ("<form role='search' method='get' class='search-form' action='http://edtechtimes.com/'><label><span class='screen-reader-text'>Search for:</span><input type='search' class='search-field' placeholder='Search &hellip;' value='' name='s'></label><button type='submit' class='search-submit'><span class='genericon-search'></span></button></form>");
($j("#mainnav")).append(search);
search = $j("#mainnav .search-form").remove();
var searchIcon = $j("a[title='search']").parent().addClass("search-icon");

//Rearrange mobile elements
var sidebar = $j(".secondary");
var social = $j("#topheader");
function arrange() {
    if ($j(window).width() <= 960) {
        sidebar.insertAfter($j("#post-slider-container"));
        social.appendTo($j("#navigation-wrap"));
        search.appendTo(searchIcon);
    } else {
        sidebar.insertAfter($j("#content"));
        social.prependTo($j("#header-wrap"));
        search.appendTo($j("#mainnav"));
    }
}

$j(document).ready(arrange);
$j(window).resize(arrange);
```

Comment: can you create http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Not the best but replace $j with jQuery and remove $j = jQuery.noConflict(), may help.

Comment: @MKA , it's an entire wordpress site so I'm not sure how I would create a fiddle for that.